# Azure Event Grid deploy fails due to 'cannot update during provisioning'

Tags: azure-eventgrid

We have an Event Grid with a couple of Functions attached to it as listeners. We're doing some load tests and are seeing a lot of functions fail, which means that event grid will resend those events.

However, if we try to redeploy Event Grid (using ARM), we get the following exception: 'Resource cannot be updated during provisioning'. So far, the only thing we've found that works to deploy it is to tear down the existing Event grid and deploy a fresh one, obviously not ideal. Is this a known issue, or are we doing something weird?

Comment: Was your issue resolved? I am getting a similar error.